# Google Play Games - Unable to sign in - load the player

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, oauth, integration, google-play-games

Im making Android endless runner game in Unity and I have a problem with integration of Google Play Games.

Whenever I start the game, I see the loading logo of this service for a second and then nothing more happens. I dont see the name nor the level of the player and leaderboard doesnt work either.

Im using CloudOnce asset - I followed this tutorial - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=34v_Il5bFz8

The service - the asset - seem to work fine, but the problem seem to be the connection. I suspect the certificates? I even added the publish sha1 certificate from unity keystore to the Google API manager but it didnt solve that.

Does anyone have any suggestions how to solve this please?
Thank :)